# Issue with Linked List, Vector and pointers

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

OK, here's my issue :

- I've implemented a `Move class`, with a variable `Move *subMove` pointing to a "subMove"
- I'm having a list (`vector` of `Move`s which I'm looping through, using `vector<Move>::iterator`)
- I have a **global Move object** (let's say the 'root' of our linked list), with which our function is initially called
- I'm trying to assign current move (from the loop) to my current root's *subMove field*.

And here's how issues arise...

**My code (roughly) looks like this :**

```
int Game::doSth(Move & pv)
{
    vector<Move> moves;
    this->possibleMoves(moves);
    for (std::vector<Move>::iterator move = moves.begin(); move!=moves.end(); ++move)
    {
        // Do sth
        int subResult = this->doSth(*move);
        if (someConditionIsTrue)
        {
            // yep, we want to store THIS move as a submove

            // This works - without memory errors - 
            // but still something goes weird, so I'd prefer creating a new object
            pv.subMove = &(*move);

            // Also tried something along the lines of `pv.subMove = new Move(*move)`
            // - yes there is an appropriate copy constructor - 
            // but this leads to a `segmentation fault` error
        }
    }

    // return something;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: “doesn’t work” is an insufficient problem description. The code compiles, right? What’s the issue?

Comment: @KonradRudolph The issue is as straightforward as this : why does `pv.subMove = new Move(*move);` trigger a segmentation fault, while `pv.subMove = &(*move);` works (even though a bit messing up the result...)?

Comment: Do you have a proper copy-constructure that does _deep_ copying?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Please, post your answer as a typical answer and I will gladly accept it at once so that you get all the credit you deserve. And yep, that was it. To the point. Tack så mycket! :-)

Comment: Does your `doSth` function do some crazy stuff with `*move`?

Comment: @JatinGanhotra Nope, it doesn't. (Btw, the correct answer has been given moments ago in the comment above ^).